# Limit of $f(x,y)$

Tags: limits

I have a hard time evaluating 
$$
\lim_{(x, y)\to(0, 0)} \frac{e^{xy}\sin(xy)}{xy}
$$

I keep getting the answer that the limit doesn't exist but actually the answer is $1$. Help.

Comment: How do you know what the answer is supposed to be? And why don't you show us your work, so we can point out the error?

Comment: Are you able to determine the similar limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x \sin x}{x}$?

Comment: Make the change of variable $r=xy$. Then use that $r\to 0$ if and only if $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. To solve for $r$ just use the L'Hopitals rule or the fact that $\sin(r)\sim r$ when $r\sim 0$.

Comment: @Jonh: Is "only if" true or necessary?

Comment: @BrianTung I didn't meant to write it as some implication. I was trying to say that it os equivalent. Either way it is true, although the only if part might not be necessary

Comment: @Jonh It is not true that $xy \to 0$ implies $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. To see this, let $x$ be any fixed nonzero number and let $y \to 0$. Then $xy \to 0$ but $(x,y) \not\to (0,0)$. Fortunately for this problem, we only need the reverse implication, $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ implies $xy\to 0$, which is true (see my answer below).

Comment: @Bungo Absolutely, sorry, hurry-silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(x,y) \to 0$ if and only if $x^2 + y^2 \to 0$. This fact combined with the inequality $|xy| \leq (x^2 + y^2) / 2$ means that the following chain of implications holds:
$$(x,y) \to 0 \implies x^2 + y^2 \to 0 \implies xy \to 0$$
This justifies rewriting the problem by setting $u = xy$ and taking the limit as $u \to 0$:
$$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^u \sin(u)}{u} = \left(\lim_{u \to 0}e^u\right) \left( \lim_{u \to 0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\right) = (1)(1) = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Recall from elementary geometry that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x \tag 1$$

for $|x|\le \pi/2$.  Then, we have from $(1)$

$$\cos(xy)\le \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}\le 1 \tag2$$

---

> In addition, I showed in [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the exponential function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$$
>
> for $x<1$

---

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ together, we have

$$(1+xy)\cos(xy) \le \frac{e^{xy}\sin(xy)}{xy}\le \frac{1}{1-xy}$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem reveals

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{e^{xy}\sin(xy)}{xy}=1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the Taylor series $$e^{xy} = 1 + xy + \frac{x^2y^2}{2} + \frac{x^3 y^3}{6} +\cdots$$ and $$\sin(xy) = xy - \frac{x^3y^3}{6} + \frac{x^5y^5}{120} \pm \cdots$$ and you'll end up with the representation $$\frac{e^{xy}\sin(xy)}{xy} = 1 + \mathcal O(xy)$$ which holds as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can try polar coordinates for any point where the function is defined.:

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t\end{cases}\implies \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}e^{xy}\frac{\sin xy}{xy}=\lim_{r\to0}e^{r^2\cos t\sin t}\frac{\sin r^2cos t\sin t}{r^2\cos t\sin t}=e^0\cdot1=1$$